# Angular: Style based on property

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I want to style a div based on a bool property "isActive" on my controller.
Is this possible with angular?

```
<div class="col-md-3" (click)="isActive = !isActive">
    <div class="center">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><br>
        <span>Activate</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional class:

```
<div class="col-md-3" (click)="isActive = !isActive">
    <div class="center">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><br>
        <span [class]="isActive? 'classA': 'classB'">Activate</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to change the parent div while keeping class="col-md-3"?

Comment: Use this on parent:
`[class]="isActive? 'classA': 'classB'"`
where classA = "col-md-3 myclassA"?

Comment: and classA is my SCSS style?

Comment: Yes. Define multiple classes in your stylesheet and use them in the conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, consider using attribute directives. For example to apply some class to a div based on some boolean value use this syntax in div:
`div [class.some_class]="isActive"`.

If you want to choose it's content based on some value consider using `*ngIf` structural directive (or `ngSwitch`). For example 
`<div> <h1 *ngIf="isActive">I'm ActiveM</h1> </div>`

Read more here: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Also if you have list of some classes and correspoding boolean values that define whether the class is used or not in your controller style, then use following:

in your ts file:

```
this.currentClasses =  {
    'saveable': this.canSave,
    'modified': !this.isUnchanged,
    'special':  this.isSpecial
  };
```

in template file use `ngClass`:

```
<div [ngClass]="currentClasses">This div is initially saveable, unchanged, and special</div>
```

Code is from: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngclass